# Read smart card data with APDU

Tags: smartcard, apdu, acr122

I'm using an ACR122U-A9 for reading my smart card and with the following APDU I can get the UID and ATS:

```
UID: FF CA 00 00 00
ATS: FF CA 01 00 00
```

Using the NXP TagInfo app (android) I can see a HEX table with the data that I need. With what APDU command can I retrieve these data?

Hex table looks like this:

```
[0000] 00 00 00 00 74 65 73 74 [test]
[0008] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [......]
```

In [0000] are the data that I want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you haven't mentioned in your question that which type of tag yo are using (T2T, T4T etc.).
If you are using T2T, you can't directly access the first 10 bytes as they are internal bytes.
If you can access the initial APDU transfer of the Activation sequence, there you can find the UID transferred from card to reader.

A open api java and android library is available called "TapLinx" provided by NXP itself. For ease of use you can make use of this library free.

Cheers!